# Generalization of Commutativity For Unions of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Paul Halmos' book on naïve set theory (or axiomatic set theory in a naive point of view) in the chapter about families is provided a generalization of associativity for unions of sets:

$\bigcup _{i\in I_j}A_i = \bigcup_{j\in J}(\bigcup_{i\in I_j}A_i)$

such that $\{I_j\}$ is a family indexed by the index set $J$, and $\{A_i\}$ is a family indexed by the index set $\{I_j\}$

As I believe I understood here, the number of paranthetical groups of unions of members of $\{A_i\}$ depends on the size of $\{I_j\}$, and the number of elements in union within each paranthetical group depends on how many members are in the sets $I_j$ in the family $\{I_j\}$.

*(It would be kind if someone could confirm whether my apprehension is correct)*

The book then challenges the reader to try and construct a generalization for the commutativity of unions of sets. The way I reasoned was as follows: commutativity refers to the fact that the union of two sets denotes the same result whether it's the first set to the second, or the second to the first; hence I could easily generalize commutativity over the union of two sets as:

$(\bigcup_{i\in I_1}A_i)\bigcup$ $(\bigcup_{i\in I_2}A_i) = (\bigcup_{i\in I_2}A_i) \bigcup$ $(\bigcup_{i\in I_1}A_i)$

However, this is only generalized over two sets. And I have trouble expressing this most generally. It is requested that the reader help me complete the task so required. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think commutativity for a union of a "family" of sets makes no sense. I wonder what is the exact formulation of the book's "challenge".

Comment: I think perhaps the phrasing has led to misinterpretation. By a family we mean the range of an index function such as $\{A_,A_2, ... ,A_i\}$ and by a union we mean $\bigcup \{A_1, A_2, ... ,A_i\}$ which is the same as $A_1 \bigcup A_2 \bigcup ... \bigcup A_i$. Hence the challenge is to generalize the commutativity of the unions. If the family is a two-element set, that would be $A_1 \bigcup A_2 = A_2 \bigcup A_1$. Have I reached clarity?

Comment: There was no misinterpretation, that is what I understood (including infinite *non-ordered* "families", i.e. sets, in which case there is no "which is the same as..."), and I still find the "challenge" nonsense. What is the exact formulation of the book?

Comment: "The algebraic laws satisfied by the operation of union for pairs can be genralized to arbitrary unions. Suppose for instance, that $\{I_j\}$ is a family of sets with domain $J$, say; write $K = \bigcup _j I_j$, and let $\{A_k\}$ be a family of sets with domain $K$. It is then not difficult to prove that $\bigcup _{i\in I_j}A_i = \bigcup_{j\in J}(\bigcup_{i\in I_j}A_i)$; This is the generalized version of the associative law for unions. Excersize: formulate and prove a generalized version of the commutative law."

Comment: Thank you (alas it does not help as much as I hoped). btw the lhs is not $\bigcup _{i\in I_j}A_i$ but $\bigcup _{i\in K}A_i,$ where $K=$ more precisely $\cup_{j\in J}I_j,$ isn't it?

Comment: Ah, my bad. Yes, you are correct. But I'm not seeing what exactly causes the impasse in understanding?

Comment: My problem is that $\{1,2\}$ is implicitely ordered, whereas there is no order on an arbitrary set $I$ of indices. May be Halmos wants us to make a "change of indices", using a bijection $\sigma:I\to I$? but then the "generalized version of the commutative law" would be a tautology, wouldn't it? My head aches. I give up. Sorry.

Comment: I seriously wonder if it might be a trick question. Halmos himself writes, on page 26f. of *Lectures on Boolean Algebras* (1974): "It is almost meaningless to speak of infinite commutative laws. An infinite supremum is something associated with a set of elements, and, by definition, it is independent of any possible ordering of
that set." One might formulate a law $$\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_{\varphi(i)},$$ where $\varphi\colon I\to I$ is a permutation, but Halmos does not define inverses of functions until the next chapter of *Naive Set Theory*, so that cannot be what he intends.

Comment: P.S. I see the system has identified a near-duplicate question (which does not, however, refer directly to Halmos's book, so it is not an exact duplicate): [The analogous generalization for the commutativity of unions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/170907). Also, [one of the answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2157130/213690) to that question does refer directly to the exercise set by Halmos.

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit I don't really understand what Halmos has in mind here. Already in order for the expression $\bigcup_i A_i$ to be unambiguously meaningful you have to know that the union of sets is commutative in the sense that it doesn't matter in what order you take this union, because the indexing set is just a set and carries no order of any kind (for example it could be an infinite set which cannot be well-ordered in a model of ZF + the negation of the axiom of choice). If this isn't true then this notation is ambiguous because then one has to specify an order in which to take the union.

Perhaps Halmos has in mind the "Fubini theorem for unions," which could be considered a kind of generalized commutativity: if $A_{ij}$ is a family of sets indexed by two sets of indices $i \in I, j \in J$, then we have

$$\bigcup_{(i, j) \in I \times J} A_{ij} = \bigcup_{i \in I} \bigcup_{j \in J} A_{ij} = \bigcup_{j \in J} \bigcup_{i \in I} A_{ij}$$

Comment: ? This is a particular case of what he called "the generalized version of the associative law for unions" (quoted at the beginning of the post and in the comments).

Comment: Ah, so it is. Well then, I really have no idea what Halmos had in mind.